# How to display value from SharePoint list to web page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a code that take the value from SharePoint List using REST (ajax), as shown as below:

```
function getItems() {  

$.ajax({  

    async: true,  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Network Tech')/items",  
    method: "GET",  

    headers: {  
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"  

    },  
    success: function(data) {  
        data = data.d.results;  
        console.log(data);  
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {  

          var value = value.Service;



        });  

    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  

    }  

  })  
}
```

I also have a HTML code for the web page, as shown as below:

```
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <h3><br><br>Networking<br></h3>
        <div class="panel-group wrap" id="bs-collapse">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading panel-bg-1">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#0101" id="v1">Virtual Networking<br></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="0101" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Coming Soon
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Right now I want to take the value from SharePoint List and display it inside the panel-body. I know how to display it on table but I don't know how to do it on this one. Please help me on this.

Comment: Change your `panel-body` to an ID (or add an ID to it), then look at how to dynamically create a table and add it to the ID Div. No need to add KnockoutJS or any other libraries. Vanilla works fine.

Comment: Thank you Matt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Library that developed by me. [Get Here](https://github.com/99xt-incubator/SPMagic)
Then you need to do small callback

```
var appUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPAppWebUrl");
var hostUrl = GetUrlKeyValue("SPHostUrl");
var list = SPMagic.ListManager(appUrl, hostUrl, "Network Tech");

list.getAllListItems("Id", 100,).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res.d.resutls);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
}
```

Then you can use [KnockoutJS](https://knockoutjs.com/) to do the Bindings for the table.

Comment: wow that's like a new things for me... I don't even have experience on KnockoutJS...haha... but thank you for the reply...

Comment: Not only KnockoutJS, You can also use it for the VueJS as well.

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much